# Three Subgroup Lemma

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove that for a group $G$ with normal subgroup $H \vartriangleleft G$ and subgroups $A,B,C \leq G$ such that $[[A,B],C] \subseteq H$ and $[[B,C],A] \subseteq H$ also $[[C,A],B] \subseteq H$. With this exercise, there was a hint to start with $H = 1$, the trivial group, which I think I proved:
Suppose $[[A,B],C] = 1$ and $[[B,C],A] = 1$, then clearly we have for all $a \in A, b \in B, c \in C$: 
$$[[a, b^{-1}],c] = 1 \quad \text{ and } \quad  [[b, c^{-1}],a] = 1.$$
This implies that 
$$b[[a, b^{-1}],c]b^{-1} = 1 \quad \text{ and } \quad  c[[b, c^{-1}],a]c^{-1} = 1$$
and by Witt's identity we have that $a[[c, a^{-1}],b]a^{-1} = 1$ hence $[[c, a^{-1}],b] = 1$. Therefore all generators of $[C,A]$ are in the centre of B, which implies that [[C,A],B] = 1.

Now to prove this for any normal subgroup $H \vartriangleleft G$. 
Suppose $[[A,B],C \subseteq H$ and $[[B,C],A] \subseteq H$. Then we have that $[[AH, BH],CH] \subseteq H$ and $[[BH,CH],AH] \subseteq H$.

Some remarks at this:
1) I'm not sure about this last step... It seems plausible to me, since the commutators are all in H, but I don't have rigorous proof for it.
2) The reason why I've tried something like that, is that I hoped to take the quotient with $H$ (and since $H$ does not need to be in $A,B,C$, I saw no other way to achieve the possibility of taking the quotient.) and end in the case were $H = 1$.

Any hints on how to complete this last step? Moreover, is the prove of the first step correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just do the whole exercise in $G/H$! Look at the canonical images in this quotient of $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Comment: No that will be $\overline{A}=AH/H$ of course. But you do the calculations with the images of the elements of $A$ etc.. Remember that $\overline{X}=\overline{1}$ in $G/H$ iff $X \subseteq H$.

Comment: So what I've wrote in my two remarks is correct? I can 'multiply' all sets by H and then work in $G/H$?

Comment: Use that $[XH,YH]=[X,Y]H$, since $H$ is normal, for any subgroups $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you very much!